# Laravel: reload page after redirecting back

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel and VueJS. I have a function with
`return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Saved!');`
that returns to a page after a form is submitted.

The form is submitted with `this.$intertia.post(api_call, data);`

Is there anyway for me to have the page automatically reload after the redirect? I have seen some other posts with suggestions to use `->refresh()` but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.reload();` should reload the page for you.

It's worth asking why you want to reload the page.

Since you are using inertia, you might be able to move towards a workflow where the relevant data is reloaded via an ajax call to an json index route and set into the existing vue component rather than fully reloading everything.